# MySQL Cross-Table Count(*) Query Help

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `t1`, `t2`
WHERE `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id`
GROUP BY `t2`.`id`
```

I want to obtain the name from t1 and the number of rows in t2 where the id is the same as on t1.

I've got the above so far, however it won't return any data if there are no rows in t2 that match. I'd prefer `count` to be 0 (or NULL) if there are no rows, and the name still returns.

*Edit:* I'd like to be able to sort by the `count` descending. (or `name` ASC) is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT `t1`.`id` , COUNT(`t2`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
GROUP BY `t1`.`id`
```

Left join ensures you have all rows from t1, and COUNT(`t2`.`id`) makes it count only records where t2.id is not null (that is - those that really exist in t2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd like to be able to sort by the `count` descending. (or `name` ASC) is that possible?

Comment: Hm... your solution shows '1' for `count` if there are now rows in t2

Comment: just add "Order by count DESC" in the end

Comment: Steve: if it shows 1 - maybe you just put COUNT(t1.id), and not COUNT(t2.id)? it makes a huge difference...

Answer (score 1):

This sorts descending by COUNT, and within same counts ascending by `name`. Names with no rows in `t2` will return with a count of 0.

```
SELECT 
  `t1`.`name`, 
  COUNT(`t2`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM 
  `t1` 
  LEFT JOIN `t2` ON`t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id`
GROUP BY
  `t1`.`name`
ORDER BY
  COUNT(`t2`.`id`) DESC,
  `t1`.`name`
```

Modify the ORDER BY to your needs.

Comment: Cheers, however `count` displays `1` when there are no rows in t2

Answer (score 0):

Do a union to get the other set

```
SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM `t1`, `t2`
WHERE `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id`
GROUP BY `t2`.`id`
UNION
Select name, 0 as count
from t1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from t2 where `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is that the most efficient/elegant way? Is there a way to do this using JOINs?